# How do I get the full compile log in Activator?

Tags: typesafe-activator

I have a large (> 25k) app that I've been developing in Scala/Akka/Play for a couple of years now. I'm in the process of upgrading it to the current version of the world (everything was a major version or two behind), which means getting it running in Activator. I'm gradually wrestling my way through that, but I'm somewhat stymied by the fact that Activator's "compile" window is very short -- only a few screens long -- so most of my 50-some-odd remaining compile errors are scrolling off the top. I'd really like to be able to read the entire thing, since I assume that most of these are knock-on errors, and only a few are really significant.

Where does the actual compile log go? How can I get to the whole thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to use the UI mode when you were happy with the command line mode in Play 2.2; the command line mode is still there, see http://typesafe.com/blog/typesafe-activator---an-update-and-roadmap-preview for some background. Just run "activator" instead of "activator ui". The UI mode is not something that's "production hardened" yet, it is primarily intended for tutorials (though we are working to change that).

That said the compile log should not be truncated in the UI and we appreciate bug reports at https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/issues including one about this truncation.

Comment: Okay, have added a bug report, and will try out the command-line version. Thanks!